# SQL wildcard search to find words from a single string that begins with the searched word?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

Let's say I've fruits table that has data 'Apple Mango Banana Guava' in a single cell.

```
declare @label nvarchar(255) = 'ango' 
select fruit from fruits 
where fruit like '%'+@label+'%'
```

With the above query, I get result for a partial match but I want it to work only if the exact word is matching from the string 'Apple Mango Banana Guava'.

> Eg: It should show me the result if I search for Mango, not for ango.

Comment: Check fulltext search. And you might do this using regular expression in your front end language.

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!  SQL has a great way to store lists.  It is called a *table*, not a *string*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've got a column called address which has multiple words in a cell & I need to perform a search on that, that's the reason I can't split the data into different columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
declare @label nvarchar(255) = 'ango' 
select fruit from fruits 
where (' ' + fruit + ' ') like '% '+@label+' %'
```

---

I strongly recommend to normalize your schema and do not store multiple values as single column.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-2017). It enables [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) predicate. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruits
WHERE CONTAINS(FruitName, '"Mango"')

SELECT *
FROM Fruits
WHERE CONTAINS(FruitName, '"Man*"')
```

The first query returns all fruits whose name contains the word Mango.

The second query returns all fruits whose name contains a word that starts with Man.